# Are min$(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and min$(X_1Y_1,\ldots,X_nY_n)$ independent for $n$ to infinity?

Tags: probability, distributions, extreme-value

Assume that we have given two continuous iid random variables $X$ and $Y$ with support $[1,c)$, where $c$ is some constant greater than one.
Now assume I have a given iid sample $X_1, \ldots,X_n$ and $Y_1, \ldots,Y_n$ (so absolutely no dependence here).

Imagine that I know that:

$$(1): \mathbb P \left(\frac{\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-a_n}{b_n}\leq x_1\right) \sim F(x_1), \text{ for }n \to \infty$$

$$(2):\mathbb P \left(\frac{\min(X_1Y_1,\ldots,X_nY_n)-\bar a_n}{\bar b_n}\leq x_2\right) \sim G(x_2), \text{ for }n \to \infty,$$

where $F$ and $G$ are just the limit distributions. Is it true that then it also follows that

$$(3):\mathbb P \left(\frac{\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-a_n}{b_n}\leq x_1,\frac{\min(X_1Y_1,\ldots,X_nY_n)-\bar a_n}{\bar b_n}\leq x_2\right) \sim F(x_1) G(x_2),$$

for $n$ to infinity?

At first I thought this cannot work since they are obviously dependent - but then I thought that the probability that $\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and $\min(X_1Y_1,\ldots, X_nY_n)$ will be obtained in the same realization will converge to zero and since the sample is iid, it is actually true?
So am I right?

---

edit:
Okay, since noone is answering so far I just explain a little bit my idea why I think it could be true; We have for some $i$:

\begin{align*}
&\mathbb P\big(X_i=\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n), X_iY_i=\min(X_1Y_1,\ldots,X_nY_n)\big) \\ \leq &\mathbb P\big(X_i=\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n), Y_i \leq \min(X_1Y_1,\ldots,X_nY_n)\big) \\
= &\mathbb P\big(X_i=\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\big) \mathbb P\big(  Y_i \leq \min(X_1Y_1,\ldots,X_nY_n) \vert X_i=\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \big) \\
= &1/n \mathbb P\big(  Y_i \leq \min(X_1Y_1,\ldots,X_nY_n) \vert X_i=\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \big)
\end{align*}

where the latter probability converges to zero, since $\min(X_1Y_1,\ldots,X_nY_n)$ gets arbitrarily close to 1 for $n \to \infty$. Therefore, the probability, that the minimum is realized in the same observation is something like $n \cdot 1/n \cdot o(1)=o(1)$, so converges to zero...

Now this is obviously not a rigorous proof but are my thoughts correct?

---

The answer can be found here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403441/are-minx-1-ldots-x-n-and-minx-1y-1-ldots-x-ny-n-independent-for-n-to/3405002#3405002

Sangchul Lee gave me a good idea, doing it with the easist case, the uniform distribution and I could extend it the general case of atom-free random variables

Comment: What are $a_n$ and $b_n$? Is it enough to focus on the case $a_n=0$, $b_n=1$?

Comment: No, it is not; You can see it as the sequences in Extreme Value Theory; In Extreme Value Theory you have something like $\mathbb P (\frac{\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-a_n}{b_n}\leq x)$ which converges to some Extreme Value Distribution, given some weak conditions; With Minima you can do the same; I think in this case, $a_n=1$ and $b_n$ goes to zero, as $n$ goes to infinity

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick thought of mine:

The condition that the product $X_i Y_i$ is smaller than $X_2$ removes all possibilities of $X_i$ being larger than $(X2_/b_n)+a_n$.

EDIT:
Yes you understood me correctly! Imagine the conditional probability of both (the product and Xi alone) being small enough: P(Xi|Xi*Yi)! Given the product Xi*Yi is small enough, since Yi must be larger than 1, there is no possibility of of Xi being larger than (x2/bn)+an. This means the conditional probability P(Xi|Xi*Yi) is always 1, if x1 is big enough. Meaning your combined probability equals G(x2), although F(x1) can still be smaller than 1.

Comment: So I think I got your idea; (I am still not sure if this is really what you want to say); If $\frac{\land XY-\bar a_n}{\bar b_n}\leq x_2$, then it holds that $\land XY\leq x_2 \bar b_n+\bar a_n$ and therefore in particular it holds that: $\land X\leq x_2 \bar b_n+\bar a_n$; So if $x_2 \bar b_n+\bar a_n \leq x_1  b_n+a_n$, then $\frac{\land XY-\bar a_n}{\bar b_n}\leq x_2$ already implies $\frac{\land X- a_n}{ b_n}\leq x_1$;

Comment: This, however, would not work if $x_2$ and $x_1$ are fixed, as $a_n=1$ and $b_n$ goes to zero and the same holds for $\bar a_n$ and $\bar b_n$; However, even if $x_1$ is infinity I don't quite think your arguments are working; Because then the probability $\mathbb P(\frac{\land X- a_n}{ b_n}\leq x_1)=1$ and then you still have equality; And even if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are defined differently, it would not work because then $\frac{\land XY-\bar a_n}{\bar b_n}$ respectively $\frac{\land X- a_n}{ b_n}$ just  converge a.s. to some number; But I still gave you a thumbs up, maybe I dont get your point..

Comment: I made an edit. I hope I understood you correctly!

Comment: I still do not understand you; In particular, I have no idea what $P(X_i | vert X_i Y_i)$ supposed to mean; But let's go a step back; I was wondering if (1) and (2) holds, that then also (3) must hold; What I did later was just an intuition why it should be correct; So right now only the equations (1), (2) and (3) matter; As I already said: $\frac{\land XY-\bar a_n}{\bar b_n}\leq x_2$ implies  $\frac{\land X- a_n}{ b_n}\leq x_1$ if $x_2 \bar b_n+ \bar a_n \leq x_1 b_n + a_n$; Do we agree on this? But this is equivalent to $x_1\geq (x_2 \bar b_n + \bar a_n- a_n)/b_n$

Comment: Now let's treat $x_2$ as some arbitrary constant and we want to show that the right term does not go to infinity which you did not prove, unfortunately; If the right term would indeed not go to infinity, you are correct.. BTW: If anyone wants to contribute to the topic, I am extremely thankful for anny remark, comment, counter example, idea for a proof etc.

Comment: Just another thought: Even if your hypothesis of uncoupled indices wasn't right, there is another thought that goes in the same direction: Given n=infinite, both probabilities for (1) and (2) will approach 0% or 100%. This means your answer will always approach truth.

Comment: Just the coupling aspect goes beyond me. I don't think it matters whether the indices of term (2) and term (1) are identical. If it is given that the product XY can be lower than a certain value and you defined certain limits for Y, then you can calculate the limits of the 1 coupled X. Basically with your logic you have to assume Y = 1 and you can directly calculate the value of coupled X. Now, imo it doesn't matter if min(Xn) = coupled X because you can show there are constellations of term (1) variables that force term (1) to be true, given there is the coupled X value. Min(Xn) <=X(coupled)

Comment: So yes, the indices might not be coupled, but the probability of term (1) being true is coupled to the probability of term (2) being true. (at least in some special cases)

Comment: I recommend you read a bit about Extreme Value Theory: If $n \to \infty$, (1) will not just go to 0 or 1 - then it would not make any sense; You probably know the Central limit theorem, right? $\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma}$ converges to a normal distribution, where $S_n$ is the sum of iid r.v. with expectation $\mu$ and standard dev. $\sigma$ given some weak condition; In Extreme Value Theory, you have something similar: $\frac{\vee x-a_n}{b_n}$ approaches on of the three Extreme Value Distributions, where $\vee$ is the maximum; For the minimum, you can do something similar;

Comment: Also check the same question on math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403441/are-minx-1-ldots-x-n-and-minx-1y-1-ldots-x-ny-n-independent-for-n-to I added a bunch of explanations :-)

Comment: Are a, b and small x constant throughout the infinite series? And big X is a random number? This means you have a certain probability per X to result in a true statement. This probability is either 0 or greater 0. In case it's greater 0, this is just a binomial distribution with n draws. And if it's 0, it stays 0.

Comment: I will read though your recommendations! Thanks! Btw: If your variables are not constant, then Xi and Yi would need to be coupled in order for (2) to influence the probability of (1). So your hypothesis is true.

Comment: You can use $\LaTeX$ formatting on this site, I started, please complete. You can have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks, I wondered how people are doing this. I will study this tutorial, edit this thread and from now on use Latex.